# Show that a group of order 2016 has a subgroup of order 28

Tags: abstract-algebra

How would one go about showing that a group of order 2016 has a subgroup of order 28?

I know that I should begin by factoring 2016 as $2^5.3^2.7$. I think Sylow's theorems will also come into play, so it seems relevant to compute $n_7$. We know that $n_7\equiv 1 \mod 7$ and $n_p | 2^5.3^2$, so the possible values of $n_7$ are $1, 8$ but where to go from here?

Comment: See [here](http://www.math.ucsc.edu/graduate/phdprogram/prelims/tests/algebra-f2016.pdf), exercise $1$.

Comment: yes. Thats the source of the problem, but it doesn't help solve it...

Comment: Then it is homework?

Comment: No. It is not homework. It is an old preliminary exam problem (see the title of the document). I'm studying for future prelims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Sylow's theorems, there exists a sylow 2-subgroup $G_1$ and a sylow 7-subgroup $G_2$.

Note any p-subgroups $G$ have non-trival center $Z(G)$.
Now you can choose $a \in Z(G_1)$ and $b \in Z(G_2)$ which implies that both $A=\langle a \rangle$ and $B=\langle b \rangle$ are normal.

Since $|G_1|=8$ and $|A|=2$, you can choose another $c \in G_1$ of order 2. Let $C=\langle c \rangle$ .

Finally, $D=A\times B\times C$ is a subgroup of order $2\cdot 2 \cdot 7=28$.

Comment: But why does the original group necessarily have a subgroup isomorphic to $A\times B\times C$?

Comment: @user140776 Note that $B$ is a normal subgroup and either $A$ or $C$ can be normal subgroup if $a \ in Z(G)$ or $c\ in Z(G)$  where $Z(G)$ is the center of 2-subgroup. Maybe I make some mistakes in the answer and they are corrected now.